# Automatically insert user prompt in DOS/System via Matlab

Tags: windows, matlab

In Matlab, using the `dos()` (or `system()`) command it is possible to run command line scripts via Matlab itself.

Let's say I have a script called, `dummy.exe`, which does not need any input parameters; that is, nothing like

> dummy.exe -flag1 arg1 -flag2 arg2 ...

Rather, during its execution, it prompts the user for some variables.

It is possible to automatically feed user prompts?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the solution you are looking for:

```
tmp = tempname();

fid = fopen(tmp,'wt');
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',answer_1);
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',answer_2);
fprintf(fid,'%s\n',answer_3);
fclose(fid);

system(sprintf('"%s" < "%s"','dummy.exe',tmp));

delete(tmp);
```